# How do you check if a property is undefined in qml?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, programming, qml

How do you check if a property is undefined in qml?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Button {
    id: myButton
    text: if (text === "undefined"){"default text"}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:
`text: text ? text : "default text"`

`"undefined"` is just a string representation of a reference not referencing anything, just like `None`, or `NULL` in other languages.

`===` is strict comparison operator, you might want to read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: That was a very clever solution. Thanks. Just to explain to anyone else; its sort of like saying (correct me if I am wrong) if (text === text){text} else{"default text"}

Comment: `if (text) { text } else {"default text"}` to be exact.
`if (object)` evaluates to false if `object` is undefined. Similar hack to C-style if(pointer) that evaluates to false if pointer has a value of 0 (NULL).
It's worth noting that `text` variable used for text property of a button is taken from outside scope. It'll be much clearer with: `text: inText ? inText : "default text"`, or `if(inText) { text } else {"default text"}`

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but this is something I never quite understood. In logic, it would technically read as this - `if (text is true) then {text = text} else {text = "default text"}` -- is this accurate?

Comment: You're pretty much right. The only unintuitive thing about this pseudo-code is `if (text is true)`. I find it easier to think as `if (text *is*)` or `if (text exists)`.
Another good source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: This will fail with text = "" (empty string), the if will return false

Answer (score 7):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Button {
    id: myButton
    text: text ? text : "default text"
}
```

This answer throws a warning for me.

```
QML Button: Binding loop detected for property "text"
```

Changing `text` to `modelText` instead throws an error.

```
ReferenceError: modelText is not defined
```

This stops the Javascript execution for me; i.e. the next line isn't called.

### Via Javascript

The same happens when setting it via Javascript, but is quite verbose.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Button {
    id: myButton
    text: "default text"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (modelText !== "undefined") {
            myButton.text = modelText;
        }
    }
}
```

### Using `typeof`

The `typeof` operator mutes the error and works as expected.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Button {
    id: myButton
    text: "default text"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (typeof modelText !== "undefined") {
            myButton.text = modelText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To compare with undefined you write `text === undefined`. This will evaluate to false if `text` is `null`.

If you want check if value is present (i.e., check for both `undefined` and `null`), use it as condition in if statement or ternary operator. If you need to store result of comparison as a boolean value, use `var textPresent = !!text` (though double `!` might appear confusing to one reading the code).